# import android_view_TextureView not found

Tags: java, android, import

i can't import `android.view.TextureView`.

All other import work except `android.view.TextureView`.  i download the `textureView.java` but can't compile, because of other unknown type like `private HardwareLayer mLayer`.
i see that every body import it without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) was added in API level 14.
 In order to use it, you must target your app to at least this API level.